# How do I renew a letsencrypt SSL certificate on fresh box using certbot?

Tags: linux, ssl, lets-encrypt

I have an SSL certificate issued by https://letsencrypt.org/ . It will be expiring tomorrow and I am having trouble renewing it. I have spun up a fresh linux box, installed certbot (as per https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/ ) . I have the following saved in a local directory:

```
cert.pem
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
```

Within the directory that contains the certificate I then run

```
/path/to/certbot/certbot-auto renew --dry-run --force-renew
```

certbot appears to not find the certificates as it then says

```
No renewals were attempted.
```

I have also run

```
/path/to/certbot/certbot-auto renew --force-renew
```

and get the same response.

Is there a way to renew certificates that are not stored in the expected /letsencrypt/archive/... folder as is the case for a fresh installation on a fresh box?

Comment: Why bother renewing them - why not just create new certificates on the new box?